# Filters or Interceptors? How to pre-modify all queries in a session in a certain way?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been looking around for some time now and I still can't really decide whether it is filters that I need or interceptors with onPrepareStatement().

My use case is the following: After a user logs in to my app, depending on several complex decisions this user gets certain access privileges and depending on them has (or doesn't have) access to certain data. I thought the simplest way to implement this would be to "join" each and every query with some restriction, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM sumfin WHERE cond1 and cond2;
```

Here `cond2` is the restricting condition. So basically I want to append `and cond2;` to all my existing queries. What's the best way to do that in java using hibernate?

Comment: This seems the wrong way to do this. Use database views and a multitenant session factory...

Comment: this actually sounds quite reasonable, thanks @bmorris591, I'll take a closer look at the multitenant session factory.

Comment: @bmorris591 multitenancy in hibernate really seems like a blessing and I wondered how come I haven't used it earlier... And then I suddenly knew the why of it :) Sadly, I'm only allowed to use hibernate3.6. So my question still stands.